# Unable to understand error angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

```
ERROR in ./src/scss/style.scss (./node_modules/raw-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/scss/style.scss)
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)
    at Object.getInstalledBinaries (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:129:13)
    at foundBinariesList (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:20:15)
    at foundBinaries (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:15:5)
    at Object.module.exports.missingBinary (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\errors.js:45:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:15:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:24:22)
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.9.2 was found instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says,

**`The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.9.2 was found instead.`**

In your project folder run again

**`npm install typescript@2.7.2`**

Comment: getting this error 

ERROR in ./src/app/views/duplicatebill/duplicatebill.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\vendor'
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:904:18)
    at Object.getInstalledBinaries (C:\Users\arsalan.akhtar\Documents\KEweb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:129:13)